# 'surf' error X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex (matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I'm trying to plot `Ackley Function` in `matlab` But I'm getting the following error

> Error using surf (line xxx)
>
> X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.

Here's the code I'm using

```
clear; clc; close all;
% Parameters
nx = 2;                 % No. of Input variables
f = @ackley;
limits = repmat([-40 40], nx, 1);
titl = 'Ackley';

% Plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(limits(1,1),limits(1,2),100),...
                     linspace(limits(2,1),limits(2,2),100));
Z = reshape(f([X(:)'; Y(:)']), 100, 100);

surfc(X,Y,Z);
```

`Ackley.m`

```
function [y] = ackley(x)
    d = length(x);
    a = 20;
    b = 0.2;
    c = 2*pi;

    term1 = -a * exp(-b*sqrt(1/d * sum(x)));
    term2 = -exp(1/d * sum(cos(c * x)));

    y = term1 + term2 + a + exp(1);
end
```

Comment: It should be `sum(x).^2`

Comment: @hbaderts or `sum(x.^2)`

Comment: @hbaderts But still I'm getting wrong plot with the above code.

Comment: have you checked the values of X, Y, Z? are there any complex values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *hbaderts* mentioned, when you change the Ackley function as follows, your code works:

```
function [y] = ackley(x)
    d = length(x);
    a = 20;
    b = 0.2;
    c = 2*pi;

    term1 = -a * exp(-b*sqrt(1/d * sum(x.^2)));
    term2 = -exp(1/d * sum(cos(c * x)));

    y = term1 + term2 + a + exp(1);
end
```

Comment: I'm getting wrong figure after fixing the error as you mentioned. I'm getting this plot
https://s17.postimg.org/kqe7lo5cv/Capture2.png
But I'm expecting this plot 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Ackley%27s_function.pdf/page1-640px-Ackley%27s_function.pdf.jpg

Comment: which plot are you expecting? is you function correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting negative arguments for your sqrt() calculation in `term1 = -a * exp(-b*sqrt(1/d * sum(x)));`. Adapt your plotting range. e.g. `limits = repmat([0 40], nx, 1);`